# How to configure mapserver correctly on cherokee?

Tags: mapserver

I am attempting to configure mapserver using fastcgi on cherokee and here's what I have got at the moment:-

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Unfortunately, that doesn't seem to be enough as I somehow need to have mapserv running as a process.  But I don't see such an option for mapserver in its docs.

Any suggestion how I may configure mapserver correctly on cherokee?